# How to enforce Uses-Feature during install on device

Tags: android, uses-feature

Android Manifest allows definition of Uses-Feature capabilities, like frontcamera. They are checked in the store before download of the App but it seems if the App is sideloaded there is no check on the Phone if the capabilities are available. Is there any posibility to tell android to check them while installing an app?

Comment: I don't think so. You can use `PackageManager` to find out if the device has the feature, and use that to supply your own warnings or otherwise take action.

Comment: OK that's also what I think is the only Option.